# Wrapping "stop" keyword as a function name

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to convert a C# code to VB.NET.

The C# reads:

```
    [DllImport("IrisAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void stop();
```

When I write the same in VB.NET, it looks like this:

```
    <DllImport("IrisAPI.dll", CallingConvention := CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Public Shared Sub stop()
    End Sub
```

But "stop" is a keyword of VB.NET, and the compiler won't let me do that.

How would I have to wrap this up to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe capitalizing the word would escape the reserved keyword ! like `Stop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`EntryPoint` property of the attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint):

```
<DllImport("IrisAPI.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint:="stop")>
Public Shared Sub custom_name_here()
```

Answer (score 1):

The brackets around stop seem to fix it. This was the suggested fix provided by intellisense.

```
<DllImport("IrisAPI.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Sub [Stop]()
End Sub
```

Comment: You _can_ use square brackets in VB.Net in order to use reserved words as names, but it's probably best avoided if possible.